# spring batch: NullPointerException in CustomItemWriter when executing jobs asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, spring-batch

I am using spring batch with version 4.2.1.RELEASE. I have one job, which i run multiple times with diferrent job parameters. When executing the jobs synchronous everything works fine. When i try to run the jobs asynchronous i am getting a NullPointerException while attempting to get some value from the execution context in a CustomItemWriter. The Jobs are scheduled by a Job Scheduler.

CustomItemWriter

```
public class CustomWriter ItemWriter<T>, StepExecutionListener {
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        customObject = (CustomObject) Objects.requireNonNull(executionContext.get("custom_object")); -> Exception when running asynchronous
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CustomWriter> list) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

BatchConfig

```
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("batchDataSource")
    private DataSource batchDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") final DataSource batchDataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchDataSourceInitializer batchDataSourceInitializer(
            @Qualifier("batchDataSource") final DataSource batchDataSource, final ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        return new BatchDataSourceInitializer(batchDataSource, resourceLoader, new BatchProperties());
    }

    @Override
    public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer defaultSerializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
        defaultSerializer.setObjectMapper(JsonUtils.getObjectMapper());

        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
        factory.setSerializer(defaultSerializer);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}
```

MainClass

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({BatchConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, MainJobConfig.class})
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Exception (occurs only when executing the jobs asynchronous)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at com.aldisued.tcmapp.chunks.writer.CustomItemWriter.beforeStep(CustomItemWriter.java:22)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:204)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

JobScheduler

```
@Component
public class JobScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("asyncJobLauncher")
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron.expr}")
    public void runJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, InterruptedException {
        runJobs(getStringList();
    }

    private void runJobs(List<String> stringList) throws JobParametersInvalidException,
            JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        for (String string : stringList) {
            JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addDate("exec_time", new Date())
                    .addString("exec_time", string)
                    .toJobParameters();

            jobLauncher.run(job, params);
        }
    }

    private List<Strings> getStringList() {
        // get some strings
    }
}
```

How do i make the execution threadsafe or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Objects.requireNonNull(executionContext.get("custom_object"))`, you are requiring `executionContext.get("custom_object")` to be non null here, are you sure the code that adds the key `custom_object` is executed before that line when you run the job asynchronously?

Comment: Yes 100% sure. I just tried to create a minimal example. In the first step of the job the CustomObject gets created and saved in the execution context. The other steps put some data into the CustomObject instance. If the code wouldnt add the key "custom_object" it wouldnt work when executing the steps synchronous.

Comment: `it wouldnt work when executing the steps synchronous`: that's the point, the order is not the same when going asynchronous.. `I just tried to create a minimal example`, if you share it, I can take a look. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I will create one and post it. Thank you. But can i force the step order within a job? I thought the order is fix by creating the job with the JobBuilderFactory ("[..] .start().next().end().build [...]"). The one step which creates the Custom Object instance has to be the first step weather executing the jobs synchronous or assynchronous.

Comment: yes, but if the step itself is multi-threaded, the order can matter. You did not share that detail about your steps so a minimal example would help.

Comment: I found out that adding @JobScope to the bean step, which creates the CustomObject Instance and to the ItemReader bean steps solves the problem. Otherwise the executionContext is empty, when executing the jobs asynchronous. Nevertheless i have a new problem, because i have also a conditional step in my job... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/857